# How to insert a comma after every 8th character of a line using sed

Tags: sed

How do I insert a comma after every 8th character of a line that has alphanumeric characters including blanks?

Answer (score 3):

Take eight characters, remember them, replace them by themselves followed by a comma, repeat:

```
sed 's/\(.\{8\}\)/\1,/g'
```